# image tag within anchor tag issue

Tags: css, html, image, anchor

```
 <a id="m-tag" onclick="return false;" href="#">
  <img title="Tagit" style="width: 20%; 
   padding-top: 0px;" alt="tags" src="/images/spacer.gif">
 </a>

#m-tag{
background-image:url('images/menu-buttons.png');
width:204px;height:21px; padding-top:0px;
}
#m-tag  {background-position:0px -75px;}
```

[image]

Whats happening is my anchor tag is just about 25px height. Moreover, when i look in debugger tools in IE image occupies a whole bunch of space. But its empty. At the bottom of the image just about 25px above the end of the image space i see my image. My image does not start at the top. I will upload my description in an image[image: description]

What i see is the text "THIS SDFDS..." That is correct. When i do F12 on IE and click on the anchor tag it takes me to the bottom with the image. If I click on the image tag within the anchor tag it highlights the empty white space and the image.

I want the image to start at the top. I ideally expect to see the image from "This..." to "QQQ..SFDS" in that white space. How do i get it?

Spacer gif is a small 1 X 1 dimension image.

If this is confusing and you need more explanation, please ask. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a codepen demo?

Comment: Well since you say to at the end .. this is confusing! :) Couple things: First, why is there a spacer.gif in the image? If you set it to `display:block` and give it dimensions, you don't need anything in it at all. Second, it will be `21px` in height if that is the `height` and there is no `padding`. Third, why is the `img` set to `width:20%`?